# Any solution for this core data related exc_bad_access while setting a NSNumber attribute?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, exc-bad-access, nsnumber

So my CoreData model has one entity for the time being. It has several attributes, for testing purpose I set these attributes in the applicationdidfinishlaunching method. As soon as I set an NSNumber (Integer 16 or float) attribute it gets a EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.

The string attributes work and gets stored, I tested this with a fetch.
If I set the Integer 16 number to 0 it does not crash but I guess it's because it gets assigned nil then.

**Core data NSManagedObject created by xcode:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface ReminderSchedule : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * intervalSize;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * intervalType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * quantity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * startDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * unit;

@end
```

**Inside the applicationdidfinishlaunching method in the appdelegate**

```
ReminderSchedule *reminderSchedule;
reminderSchedule = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ReminderSchedule" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

reminderSchedule.unit = 1; <==== EXC_BAD_ACCESS
reminderSchedule.quantity = 4.0f; <==== EXC_BAD_ACCESS
reminderSchedule.name = @"this works";
reminderSchedule.intervalType = 2; <==== EXC_BAD_ACCESS
reminderSchedule.intervalSize = 2; <==== EXC_BAD_ACCESS

[self.managedObjectContext save:nil]; //just for testing, never gets here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in an 'int' and not an NSNumber.

Try this:

```
reminderSchedule.unit = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]; // this won't crash
```

You can also reformat your @property to NSInteger. This will allow you to pass in a straight integer.

Comment: Hi thank you. "= [NSNumber numberWithInt:1] gives a warning: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') from 'NSNumber *";

Comment: If I change the property to NSInteger and change the attribute type to Integer 32, it does not create the exception. But I'm sure there is something else going on and I would like to use NSNumber as it was created by xcode.

Answer (score 1):

If any of them need to be doubles you can wrap them in an NSNumber object like this:

```
reminderSchedule.quantity = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(double)]];
```

just declare the double first.

Answer (score 0):

```
 reminderSchedule.unit = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
```

This will save an NSObject of type: NSNumber, rather than a raw integer.

Comment: Thank you as well. Unfortunately this gives a warning and does not work. "= [NSNumber numberWithInt:1] gives a warning: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') from 'NSNumber *";

Comment: If you change from NSNumber to NSInteger, make sure you just assign the int, not the [NSNumber numberWithInt:1].

Comment: I did and it works that way. But I would like to know why it is not working the normal way with NSNumber numberWith.. and assign it to a generic NSNumber.

Comment: What have you set the attributes of "unit" to in your Core Data Model?